# PrimeReact DataTable custom filterFunction does nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, filtering, primereact

We're using PrimeReact in our latest project, and we have a filter we want to implemented where the column data is an array and we want the user to be able to select an array of options to filter that column by. (So the column represents assigned users and the filter would be a multiselect of users to filter by).

This would require a filter mode of CUSTOM, and the documents mention a filterFunction property on columns, but absolutely no other details outside of that. I set the mode to CUSTOM and gave it a filter function and it does... absolutely nothing. The table automatically filters everything the moment I set the mode to custom.

Right now I'm just testing it on a string column for simplicity. Here are the filters:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
    name: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CUSTOM },
});
```

And here is the column:

```
<Column
    key="name"
    field="name"
    header="Name"
    sortable
    filter
    filterElement={searchFilterTemplate}
    filterFunction={() => console.log('test!')}
    showFilterMenu={false}
/>
```

Note: it doesn't matter what I put in filterFunction - nothing happens. Also, in the types for this method in the node_modules, filterFunction on the Column has a return type of "void", whereas every example I've seen has a return type of "boolean", which makes waaaay more sense to me. Seems completely borked, or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: See this issue with example for more info: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/3325  In that ticket is a working Code Sandbox example of Custom Filtering